# How to find a character index in Golang?

Tags: string, go, character

I'm trying to find "@" string character in Go but I cannot find a way to do it. I know how to index characters like "HELLO[1]" which would output "E". However I'm trying to find index number of the found char.

In Python I'd do it in following way:

```
x = "chars@arefun"
split = x.find("@")
chars = x[:split]
arefun = x[split+1:]

>>>print split
5
>>>print chars
chars
>>>print arefun
arefun
```

So chars would return "chars" and arefun would return "arefun" while using "@" delimeter. I've been trying to find solution for hours and I cannot seem to find proper way to do it in Golang.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can use the [Index](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Index) function of package `strings`

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/_WaIKDWCec

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    x := "chars@arefun"

    i := strings.Index(x, "@")
    fmt.Println("Index: ", i)
    if i > -1 {
        chars := x[:i]
        arefun := x[i+1:]
        fmt.Println(chars)
        fmt.Println(arefun)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Index not found")
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are searching for non-ASCII characters (languages other than english) you need to use http://golang.org/x/text/search.

```
func SubstringIndex(str string, substr string) (int, bool) {
    m := search.New(language.English, search.IgnoreCase)
    start, _ := m.IndexString(str, substr)
    if start == -1 {
        return start, false
    }
    return start, true
}

index, found := SubstringIndex('Aarhus', 'Å');
if found {
    fmt.Println("match starts at", index);
}
```

Search the [`language.Tag` structs here](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/language#Tag) to find the language you wish to search with or use `language.Und` if you are not sure.