# How to find an exact character at a particular position in a string

Tags: go

I have the following string:

```
absoloute-power
```

As you can see, there is a "-" at position number 10 in the string.  How do I write the go code to validate if the 10th position of any given string has a "-" in the string?

Comment: What have you tried? Give example code please. This site is for programming problems, not 'write my simple code for me'. Start here - https://golang.org/pkg/strings/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find a character index in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827332/how-to-find-a-character-index-in-golang)

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/euaU-hy-Fly, in play.golang.org you could test/share what you have been doing

Comment: @nbari: Your code (https://play.golang.org/p/euaU-hy-Fly) does not do a slice bounds check. It may `panic: runtime error: index out of range`. Your code does not work for "any given string." It only works for ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

In Go, string character values are Unicode characters encoded in UTF-8. UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding which uses one to four bytes per character.

For your example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func is10Hyphen(s string) bool {
    for n := 1; len(s) > 0; n++ {
        r, size := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s)
        if r == utf8.RuneError && (size == 0 || size == 1) {
            return false
        }
        if n == 10 {
            return r == '-'
        }
        s = s[size:]
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    s := "absoloute-power"
    fmt.Println(is10Hyphen(s))
    s = "absoloute+power"
    fmt.Println(is10Hyphen(s))
    s = "absoloute"
    fmt.Println(is10Hyphen(s))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/h9rMQWWAdvb

Output:

```
true
false
false
```

---

If you are willing to consider encountering the Unicode replacement character an error, then for your example:

```
func is10Hyphen(s string) bool {
    n := 0
    for _, r := range s {
        if r == utf8.RuneError {
            return false
        }
        n++
        if n == 10 {
            return r == '-'
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/SHbPAnldTyw

Answer (score -1):

You could use a rune-array:

```
text := "ifthisisyourstring"
chars := []rune(text)
if chars[0] == '1' {
    // is true
}
```

Comment: Your code does not do a slice bounds check. It may `panic: runtime error: index out of range`. Converting the entire string to a rune slice is inefficient.

Answer (score -2):

As string is an array in fact, you can access the 10th position directly.Of course, need to avoid "out of range " error.
For the case of the non-ascii encoding, converting it to a rune array

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  fmt.Println(Check("213123-dasdas"))
  fmt.Println(Check("213123sdas"))
  fmt.Println(Check("213123das-das"))
  fmt.Println(Check("213123dasda-s"))
  fmt.Println(Check("---------2----------"))
}

func Check(ss string) bool {
  r = []rune(ss)
  if len(r) < 10 {
    return false
  }
  return ss[r] == '-'
}
```

Comment: Your code does not work for "any given string." It only works for ASCII characters.

Comment: Yes,I forgot the case

Comment: using utf8.DecodeRuneInString for the case of the invalid encoding?